# H1 tag in bootstrap bleeds outside hero-unit when resized (smaller)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a hero-unit in bootstrap and added a h1 tag. When I make the screen smaller the h1 tag bleeds outside of the hero-unit?

Hi There thank you, here is the html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>hero test</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <header class="span12 hero-unit">
    <img src="img/white.png" alt="Etc
    "class="pull-right" />
    <h1>Art Conference</h1>
    <p></p>
    <p><a href="#">Learn more</a></p>
    </header>
     </div>
</div>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Hi there, thank you here is the html

Comment: Please provide fiddle with appropriate code.

Comment: It is just using the default bootstrap css. I am on my way over to create a fiddle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can readjust the `font-size` of the `h1` according to the size of screen

```
.hero-unit h1{
     font-size: 4.4vw;
 }
```

SIDE NOTE:

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width

1vh = 1% of viewport height

1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller

1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger
```